# Buildroot plugin for eclipse-mars and up

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-neon, buildroot, eclipse-mars

I have followed the instructions in https://github.com/mbats/eclipse-buildroot-bundle/wiki/Tutorial-:-How-to-activate-and-install-the-Buildroot-Eclipse-plugin-%3F for installing the plugin.

Buildroot's server for eclipse plugins (https://buildroot.org/downloads/eclipse/) does'nt contain plugin for eclipse MARS version (v4.5).
I tried to install the 'Luna' version (v4.4) plugin but I got my toolchain list corrupted.

I tried starting-up eclipse with the -clean flag in the 'eclipse.ini' file but it didnt help either.

How can I make eclipse "register" buildroot plugin for eclipse versions higher than 4.4 ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to get help, please specify your question and show the relevant log output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The plugin supports at most Eclipse Luna at the moment. Work is on-going to support higher versions.

Comment: Is there a time table for when this will be supported?

Comment: Any news? I don't know if there is a chance or not. `BR2_ECLIPSE_REGISTER` is still in the newest version of Buildroot, but the plugin project didn't see any activity in recent years...